# If i write a tag in the literal template string, how to access it means how to add addEventListener in it?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If you write a tag in the literal template string, how to access it means how to add addEventListener in it?

Comment: You don't [add event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to tags, they're added to [elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) a tag creates. Can you please show what you have at hands, how are you using the template string?

Comment: The string with the tag is just a string until you add it to the DOM (something like `document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = someHtmlStr;`). Once it has been added, you can select it with `document.querySelector(someCssSelector);`. What `someCssSelector` should be depends on the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const htmlStr = '<div id="newElem">hover me</div>';
  document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML = htmlStr;
  
  const newElem = document.querySelector('#newElem');
  newElem.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    newElem.classList.add('hovered');
  });
  newElem.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    newElem.classList.remove('hovered');
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#newElem {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.hovered {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```